# Torsion of Bass, Farrell and Waldhausen nil groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let H be an infinite virtually cyclic group. If H is orientable (resp. non-orientable) the Farrell nil groups  $N_n(\mathbb{Z}H,\alpha) $ (resp. the Waldhausen nil groups $N^W_n(\mathbb{Z}H;\mathbb{Z}[G_1-H],\mathbb{Z}[G_1-H])$), are torsion groups?